# Is it possible to counstruct anonymous function inside of member function in such way that the parameter passed to the function is "this" object?

Tags: c++, lambda

I would like to construct anonymous-function inside of member-function of Class called Semaphore, the anonymous function takes one parameter of type "Semaphore" and the Object that should be passed is the current object calling the Method aquire(), is something like this possible and if it is possible is it considered a good style?

Consider following Code:

```
void Semaphor::aquire() {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
    //while because of spurious wakeup (OS Wakup)
    //while (numOfRessources == 0) {
        //condVar.wait(lock);
    //}
    is there any way to do the followig, so that s is "this" Object
    condVar.wait(lock, [](Semaphor s) { return s.isNumOfRessourcesZero(); });
    numOfRessources--;
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for `condVar.wait(lock, [this]() { return this->isNumOfRessourcesZero(); });`?

Comment: Since C++14 you can set variable names in [lambda captures](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda#Lambda_capture) like this `[s=this]`. Your question seems confused. What are you trying to achieve? I would guess there are better ways to get there (wherever "there" may be).

Comment: I would like to exchange the while loop 
` //while (numOfRessources == 0){//condVar.wait(lock); //}` with  
`condVar.wait(lock, [](Semaphor s) { return s.isNumOfRessourcesZero(); });`

i.e I would like to call the wait function and let the function handle spurious wake up, instead of having to implement the while loop.

hope it is clear now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for ?

```
#include <iostream>

class Test {

  void Hello(const char* name) {
    std::cout << "Hello " << name << std::endl;
  }
public:
  void DoSomething() {
    auto fFunc = [this](const char* name) {
      Hello(name);
    };
    fFunc("Marcus");
  }
};

int main()
{
  Test a;
  a.DoSomething();
}
```